# GRUB is undetected as a boot loader by BIOS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, grub

I have two SSDs in my system, I will call them s1 and s2.
I had a Linux system (Linux mint) installed on s1, and the disk manager showed me that s2 is occupied by a partition.
I wanted to use the space, and I didn't use s2 for anything, so I just formatted s2 to get free space.

Turns out GRUB was installed on s2 (as far as I understand), and therefore next time I booted the system just didn't boot, taking me to the BIOS instead.
At the time, I implemented the following hotfix: I installed another version of Linux (mint) on s1, in a different partition.
The installation came with its own GRUB instance, which luckily detected my old OS instance as a boot option and so I could boot to my old OS as a "secondary" option.
The new "dummy" OS is broken (I can't boot to it), not sure why, but I don't need it anyways.

But this has its own problems; firstly, the default boot option is the new OS, which is annoying because it is picked automatically after 10 seconds (GRUB default). Moreover, because it is the secondary option, the boot time of the old OS has increased massively from ~5s to about a minute.
Another problem is that the new OS is taking valuable space in the disk, which I will want to ideally use for the Old OS (I decresed the partition size as small as reasonable, but it the partition is still blocking me from taking the space I just freed, so it's no use, and I suspect that if I delete it altogether GRUB will be deleted as well).

I have tried a few things in order to remedy this problem for good:

1. I have installed grub-customizer in the old OS and tried to delete the boot option for the new OS (changes made from the old OS, because the new OS is not bootable), howeve,r the changes did not reflect in GRUB, probably because the GRUB instance is of the new OS but I am trying to modify the GRUB instance of the old OS.
2. I have uninstalled and installed GRUB in the old OS using boot-repair, BIOS still does not detect the GRUB instance of the old OS.

Here is a picture of s1:

[image: Picture of s1]

s2:

[image: Picture of s2]

Disk usage analyzer (might be a clue to what's going on):

[image: Screenshot from Linux mint's disk usage analyzer]

All possible boot options shown by GRUB:

[image: GRUB boot options]

All boot options in BIOS (ignore Windows boot loader, not sure why it's there):

[image: boot options in BIOS]

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: UEFI firmware does not _detect_ bootloaders. It lists bootloaders that have explicitly been added to UEFI NVRAM. If you shuffled stuff around, you need to fix those NVRAM entries.

Answer (score 1):

You can have [boot-repair-disk-image](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) that find your OS(s) and creates the grub.

In addition if your create a BootInfo summary with this tool we can get more info about the details.

[image]

Comment: From the photos, it is evident OP is using UEFI booting, as one should. Legacy booting is for legacy operating systems.

Comment: You are right. I modified my answer accordingly.